# Microsoft Word/HTML: Export textbox as <div> and not as an image

Tags: html, css, ms-word

I am creating a simple manual HTML page using Microsoft Word, and I added to it some textboxes with background and border, and with text within it.

As Microsoft Word exports these textboxes as images, instead of to regular text with CSS styled divs, this text cannot be selected or copied when viewed on the browser.

- Does anyone know if it is possible to tell Microsoft Word to export these textboxes as regular text with styling?
- If yes - how shall I do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a workaround!! Sharing it with you...

**Instead of using a text-box, use a 1x1 table**

Using Word's table styles, you can set border and background, and make it look and function like a textbox - and the text will be selectable in the web browser